# Where to put the PHPExcel Library in CakePHP 3.0

Tags: phpexcel, cakephp-3.0

I would like to know in which folder should I put/install the [PHPExcel Library](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) in my CakePHP 3.0 app.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's available via **[packagist](https://packagist.org/)**, so simply use Composer to install it, no need to manually fiddle with it.

**https://packagist.org/packages/phpoffice/phpexcel**

Comment: I installed it, but I can't include it into my controller... `Error: Class 'App\Controller\PHPExcel_IOFactory' not found`

Comment: @James **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29866131/cakephp-3-0-vendor-class-not-found**

Answer (score 2):

in folder vendor. The vendor folder is where CakePHP and other application dependencies will be installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your library file in your vendor folder and call it in your controller.
//here is the example where i am showing you how you can add library file.

//Just paste your library folder in the vendor folder. 
/*After this add this code in your controller and replace your_libarary_folder to your actual library folder also replace this line your_library_file.php to your actual file which you will use.
*/

require_once(ROOT.DS.'vendor'.DS.'your_libarary_folder'.DS.'your_library_file.php');