# CakePHP3 extending AppController namespace to third party vendor class

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm having an issue with CakePHP3 where I'm I have a SubscriptionsController and I'm trying to get an instance of a class in a third party vendor folder.

```
class SubscriptionsController extends AppController {
    public function checkDueDates() {
        require_once(ROOT .DS. "vendor" .DS. "message360" .DS. "message360.php");
        $message360 = Message360API\Lib\Message360::getInstance();
    }
}
```

getInstance() being a method of the class that returns an instance of itself if one does not exist.

However when I run this method to test if my class has been instantiated, the namespace of my instance of this class is extended by CakePHP's AppController which gives me the following error.

Class 'App\Controller\Message360API\Lib\Message360' not found

My folder is located in vendor/message360/message360.php which I'm requiring in the function. Does anyone know how to make it so that the App\Controller namespace does not get attached?

Comment: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29866131/cakephp-3-0-vendor-class-not-found**

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly I'll take note of that.